# Autoscaling continuous Azure WebJobs not working

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a few continuous web jobs setup on a azure website scaled to two to three large instances (standard mode with always on). My jobs only ever run on one of the w3wp processes. I need these to scale out but they won't. I've watched a few videos and read the docs. I have no settings.job file or anything set that should be limiting these.

Here is the source to my [job runner](https://github.com/FoundatioFx/Foundatio#jobs)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Note that when using the Kudu UI, you are connection to a single instance, and won't see processes from other instances. Try using the Processes UI built in the Preview Portal, which shows processes in all instances. I think you'll find that your WebJobs are running everywhere." @DavidEbbo