# Is there global variable in azure webjob ? How to persist data from webjob execution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-webjobs

I'm using `Azure webjob` to populate list of data , which I need to `use in my MVC Web application`.

But After executing `azure webjob` i'm not getting data inside mvc web application in that old object which I used in `azure web job`.

> Is there any global variable concept here to persist data from web job execution to mvc app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure may run your WebJobs on all your instances ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710755/will-an-azure-web-job-run-on-multiple-instances)), so your `WebJob` should be stateless (which is a good practice) and should not rely on any global variables.

To persist data, depends on your data type, I usually use **Azure Storage** (Table, Queue) to store some simple data used by my WebJobs. Or if it is related to your database, connect directly to there (Auzre SQL, SQL Server or MySQL) and persist data there.