# How to log the instance ids for webjob scaled out to multiple instances

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs

My program is currently reading from a service bus queue, and I am planning to scale out instances.
But before doing so I want to confirm if scaling is actually working tried getting the thread details but its not providing any concrete evidence

Comment: Maybe [this](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2016/11/28/how-to-manage-azure-webjobs-programmatically.aspx) article may help you.

Comment: thanks Jeroen, It was informative but I am having only one webjob which I will be running on multiple instances, I am just trying to get the proof of approach if its actually doing so

Comment: Have also a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710755/will-an-azure-web-job-run-on-multiple-instances) SO question and [this](http://www.samulihaverinen.com/web-development/dotnet/2016/02/24/guide-to-azure-webjobs/) guide.

Comment: Any update? If you feel my answer is useful /helpful.Please mark it as an answer so that other folks could benefit from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to log the instance ids for webjob scaled out to multiple instances

As far as I know, the each web app's instance will have its own instance id.

It will save as an [environment variable](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment#website-environment-variables) in its web app server.

If you want to get the current webjobs instance id, I suggest you could get its environment-variable(WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID).

The id representing the VM that the site is running on (If site runs on multiple instances, each instance will have a different id)

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue3")]  string thumbnail, TextWriter log)
        {

            string instanceid = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID");

            log.Write( "Current instance ID : "  +  instanceid);
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Brando it was very useful sorry for delayed response was inactive for few days