# Will SemaphoreSlim protect code from running twice simultaneously when Azure App Service scales out my Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, mutex, semaphore

I have an ASP .Net Core 5 Web API running on Azure App Service.
It contains a service which runs once a day, at around midnight.
So i have a System.Threading.Tasks.Timer that runs once an hour. If it is between midnight and 1am, it will start the service.
The service takes about a minute to complete, and is a loop that performs some database operations.

The other day, for some reason, it ran twice. So, while it was running, and before it finished, it ran a second instance simultaneously.

I couldn't figure out why it did this. And then I remembered that I recently set Azure App Service to scale out up to 3 instances when CPU or Memory utilization increases above 70%. Then I thought, could this be why it ran twice? While it was running, CPU or memory utilization went beyond 70%, so Azure App Service created a second instance of my Web API, which then fired the timer, which saw it was between midnight and 1AM, and so ran the service?

I thought, well, I guess it's possible. So, I thought the service needs protection against this. It should not allow two instances of it to run simultaneously (or really, in any given 24-hour period).

At first I thought about using Lock/Monitor. But my service is asynchronous, and uses the await keyword in a few places, so that wouldn't work with Lock/Monitor. SO I ended up using SemaphoreSlim. However, from my research, SemaphoreSlim only protects against interal threads executing the same code twice. It does not protect against external threads (the way, I believe, Semaphore or Mutex do).

So, to conlcude this rather lengthy post, I want to know if SemaphoreSlim will indeed protect my service from executing twice simultaneously, when Azure App Service increases the instance count of my Web API. Since it is essentially two separate instances of my API running (as far as I understand), would the second instance be seen as an external thread, and therefore not monitored by SemaphoreSlim?

Thanks

Comment: Seems what you need is a timer triggered function - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function. BTW if this is a process that just needs to run once at midnight why do you need to scale it out since it only takes 1 minute ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply auburg. I like your suggestion of using Azure Functions. Unfortunately this is a Web API which has grown too big, and is doing too many things, and needs to be refactored into micro services. I started it years ago when microservices were in its infancy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SemaphoreSlim will not protect your procedure from running simultaneously across multiple instances of your service. SemaphoreSlim will indeed lock your code *within the application's domain*, but scaling out creates a whole new instance of your web application with its own process.

You can either fix this by creating a distributed lock, perhaps through a database or cache lookup, or you can redesign your application, to run the code, which may not run simultaneously, through a separate process. Consider if it can be implemented as an [Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/), or a [webjob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create) marked as a [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21713806/1501985).

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I will look at a distributed lock as a short term solution, but I will definitely look at refactoring the API into micro services - Azure Functions or WebJobs is something i've been procrastinating for too long, and definitely need to get into.

Comment: If you have a database at hand, I understand that it could be the simplest solution, but both the function and webjob approach are not terribly complicated to implement.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have any experience with Semaphore (not SemaphoreSlim)? Apparently that uses Windows Kernel semaphores, and I suspect could work in my scenario where Azure App Service is spinning up multiple instances of my API...

Comment: @FabricioRodriguez i think you're overcomplicating this - why not just ensure one instance of your service is provisioned - why do  you need more ?

Comment: @auburg good question auburg - maybe i don't. but it was a Azure Recommendation that I enable auto scaling out of my web app. Truth is, I think the best solution here is to split up my API into micro services / azure webjobs / azure functions - it's too big, and doing too many things. If one part of the application consumes more than 70% CPU or memory, Azure App Service spins up another instance of the ENTIRE API, even though only a small subset of it was using too many resources. A bunch of micro services would work much better.